# Wordpress - ABC filter

Tags: wordpress, filtering, custom-post-type

I would like to list out the alphabet on a custom post type archive page, and by clicking on a letter in the alphabet it would link to a url that only displays posts that begin with that particular letter. Not necessarily worried about doing it ajax style or anything. Just a simple url will work.

I have this functionality on a site I developed a couple years ago (http://glenwoodia.com/business-directory/), but that was using a big business directory plugin. With this particular site I'm just using a custom post type with custom fields.

My full loop currently looks like this:

```
    <?php
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query();
        $wp_query->query('orderby=title'.'&order=ASC'.'&showposts=15'.'&post_type=businesses'.'&paged='.$paged);
    ?>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="main-area-wide">
            <div class="internal-wide">
                <div class="navigation-top">
                  <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="business-wrapper">
                    <h1>Business Directory</h1> 
                    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="business">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <p><?php $key="address"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?><br />
                        <a href="<?php $key="website"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>" target="_blank"><?php $key="website"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?></a><br />
                        <strong><?php $key="phone"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?></strong></p>
                        <p><?php $key="short_description"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="navigation-btm">
                  <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can use a plugin like : http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wp-alphabet-listing-plugin-list-all-wordpress-posts-or-pages-alphabetically-4873 and also look at the code for the queries

Comment: I found that one actually, but it doesn't even explain if it can be used for pagination. Seems to be just for listing posts by alphabet. And they have no documentation on initiating the code in your theme file. I'll keep digging. Thanks!

Comment: there are so many plugins and articles about this , it seems senseless to copy and paste one of those as an answer . you can try also this : http://www.parorrey.com/blog/wordpress/wordpress-custom-post-type-listing-by-alphabets-with-alphabetical-navigation/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this should be added as a comment, but I don't have the rep to do that. Anyway, I believe this is what you need and best of all it's documented well. I have used it before and found it pretty easy to understand:

http://www.kathyisawesome.com/424/alphabetical-posts-glossary/

Basically the same answer is also posted in Stack Exchange, be sure to scroll down to the EDIT part of the answer as that part explains the using a taxonomy thing that she did in the answer above:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41660/how-to-build-a-directory-with-indexes-in-wordpress/